# Is the function of a positive (semi) definite matrix convex?

Tags: matrices, optimization, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If you have a matrix of variables say $X=AA^{T}$ which  by definition must be either positive definite or positive semidefinite, and you have some function $f(X)$, as $X \in  C$, where $C$ is a cone, can you say that $f(X)$ is a convex function for any $f:C \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: You have more conditions on $f$?  I don't get your question, especially the last few words "for any $f : C \to \mathbb{R}$" specifying the quantifier for $f$.  Say you have a convex $f:C \to \mathbb{R}$.  Then $-f$ is concave.

Comment: Sorry, the only quantifier for $f$ is that it is maps to the reals. My question is, if such a function has as its input a positive definite of positive semidefinite matrix, for which the set of all positive (semi) definite matrices lie on a cone ( and hence convex) is the function guaranteed to be convex?

Comment: I suggest you to get to know what [quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)#Notation) means in Wiki, and re-write your question in a clearer way, instead of posting your intended question in the comments, which are treated as second-class citizens on the SE network.

Comment: See Theorem 6 in https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijanal/2015/649839/